# GPA (Grade Point Average) for/in/of

Tags: grammar, prepositions, vocabulary

The preposition suitable for this noun is quite a headache to me. Please consider the following: *I finished those programs with flying colors. The GPAs **for/in/of** the two programs were outstanding*
Which preposition is right here?

Comment: I’d be okay with either ‘for’ or ‘in’ but not ‘of’.

Comment: I'm the opposite of the previous comment. *Of* sounds the most natural to me in the ***specific*** construction used in the sentence. (And the others sound very wrong to me.) However, ***my*** GPA **for/in** sounds more natural to me than ***my*** GPA **of**. In other words, if it's preceded by a possessive pronoun, I would use *for* or *in*, but if it's preceded by an article, I would use *of*. ***The*** *GPA **of** the students was high.* ***The*** *average GPA **of** the class was high.* And the sentence in the question is the same.

Comment: Then again, in the context of the passage in the question, I wouldn't use *the GPAs* in the first place. I'd use *my GPAs* …

Comment: Programs or courses? Courses usually have grades; students have GPAs. “My grades were outstanding in both of these programs . . . “